# Python rotational cipher script issue

Tags: python

So basically I am writing a tool to brute force all the possible answers to a alphabet rotational cipher, then print them all out to the screen. How do I keep special characters and spaces from rotating and just leave them as they are.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# alphabeth and key variables

import sys

alpha_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
alpha_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cipher_text = sys.argv[1]

def crack_rotation():

    for key in range(len(alpha_lower)):
        plain_text = ''

        for character in cipher_text:
            if character == character.lower():
                index = alpha_lower.find(character)
                index = (index-key)%len(alpha_lower)
                plain_text += alpha_lower[index]
            else:
                index = alpha_upper.find(character)
                index = (index-key)%len(alpha_upper)
                plain_text += alpha_upper[index]

        print('Trying with key %s. Result = %s' %(key, plain_text))

crack_rotation()
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your innermost loop check for the character not being in your alphabets and skip the rest of the loop if it isn't.

```
if character not in alpha_upper + alpha_lower:
    plaintext += character
    continue
```